# service name is not resolved

Tags: java, android, android-service

The error I'm referring to in this question has its share of questions in SO. However, I've looked through like 20 questions but none of them has talked about this error with an Android service. I'm trying to turn a video into a live wallpaper, I'm reading through [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-live-wallpaper-on-android-using-an-animated-gif--cms-23088) in which I'm supposed to create a dedicated service for the wallpaper:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.asgardia.peacelivewallpaper">


<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service android:name="com.asgardia.peacelivewallpaper.peacelivewallpaperservice"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:label="GIF Wallpaper"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
            android:resource="@xml/peacelivewallpaper" >
        </meta-data>
        <uses-feature
            android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"
            android:required="true" >
        </uses-feature>
    </service>
</application>
```

In a question here in SO, the problem was that the poster was supposed to add the package name to .java class whose name is the same as the service. I added a new class to `app/java/<package-name>/java` with a name `peacewallpaperservice.java`, I've added this class because from I can comprehend every service needs a class with the same name, this however didn't seem to do much. I still get the `error: cannot resolve symbol peacelivewallpaper`. I'd appreciate some help.

As it's mentioned in the tutorial, I'm supposed to create an engine to decode the GIF file:

```
public class GIFWallpaperEngine extends WallpaperService.Engine {
    private final int frameDuration = 20;

    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Movie movie;
    private boolean visible;
    private Handler handler;

    public GIFWallpaperEngine(Movie movie) {

        this.movie = movie;
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        this.holder = surfaceHolder;
    }

}
```

Comment: From what you have written in the post, peacelivewallpaperservice (of your manifest) it's different from peacewallpaperservice.java (the service class). Moreover you should use CamelCase class names and don't forget to extend Service class

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it's working just fine now

Comment: Glad to help you ^^